# Find text node, then wrap in tags

Tags: jquery, textnode

I have the following bit of HTML, which I do not have control over:

```
<div id="sub-nav">
Vendita diretta            
<ul class="cms-nav-sidebar">            
<li class="icl-level-1"><a href="/tasting/">Degustazioni</a></li>
</ul>                           
</div>
```

I need to wrap the first bit of text within the "sub-nav" `div`, in an `<h1>` tag. So far i've got this:

```
$('#sub-nav').children().wrap("<h1></h1>");
```

However, this wraps all elements within the `div` in the `h1` tag. How can I pinpoint just the first text node and wrap that in the `h1`?

Thanks
Dave

Comment: jquery's not particularly good at all for dealing with text nodes. might be better off working outside of jquery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/298750/901048

Comment: Thanks @Blazemonger. Taking the last example in that thread, I use like this: var myText = $('#sub-nav').contents(':not(ul)').text(); - how would it be possible to then use the myText variable to wrap that value in an h1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working off of the link in Blazemonger's comment...

```
$('#sub-nav').contents(':not(ul)').wrap("<h1></h1>");
```

...ought to work in your case.

Comment: Though, I will admit it is highly specific and rife with odd side effects.

Comment: Well, it works :) In this case the specificity is OK, as the sub menues will follow that order > text node > ul

Comment: Not an ideal solution, or one that could be used in other situations, but in my case, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#sub-nav').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3; //text node type
}).eq(0).wrap("<h1></h1>");
```